# Configure android project with cocos2dx

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have done a cocos2dx iOS project with c++. Now I want to export it to android. I have read the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) to configure eclipse and all the sdks I need. My example project works fine so I start with the port.

To develop the iOS project we have did a little framework to help us to communicate with cocos2d in a isometric game. The first problem comes in the framework import, how I should do it? In Xcode We have a header search folder that recursively search all headers in a folder and the inner folders, thats anything similar to configure eclipse?

The main project and the library uses booth library, how I should import it to eclipse? As a include path?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly want but how to include path in eclipse is by Right Clicking the project -> C++ General -> Path & Symbols -> C++ GNU You can include path over there ..

Comment: Follow this : Combining the iOS and Android Project Structures  on this link ..http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started  [will surely help ]